# Speech Synthesizer "SpeakAsyncCancelAll" runs in user interface thread

Tags: c#, winforms, accessibility

I have a Windows forms application that I am trying to add accessibility to and have run into an issue with the speech synthesizer where it appears that the SpeechAsyncCancelAll runs in the user interface thread.  Performance is totally dependent on the power of the PC.
This can be reproduced with a very simple application in Windows forms.
Create a form and add a numeric up down control.  Then use this code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace WindowsFormsApp8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer _speech = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _speech.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
            _speech.SpeakAsync(numericUpDown1.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

On my development machine which is very powerful it runs without a problem and very fast when you hold down the up arrow.  Each value is cancelled so you do not hear anything as the control increments and when you stop pressing the up arrow it announces the last value properly.
However, the minute this is run on a lesser PC, even a core i9 hexacore machine, the repeat on the increment slows to a crawl.
It looks to me that this is running on the user interface thread.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Is it because the repeat setting on your PC is different to the default?

Comment: Is your SpeechSynthesizer object connected to a natively available synthesizer, i.e. SAPI, or to an active screen reader (Jaws or NVDA) ? Do you have tested if the value is correctly announced when a screen reader is running ? If your numeric control were naturally accessible, you shouldn't have to manually notify when the value changes.

Comment: One of the computers has a completely fresh install of Windows 10.

Comment: The SpeechSynthesis object is part of .NET.  It is native.  No screen readers are involved.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer?view=netframework-4.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't get yourself tricked by the "Async" in the name of the `SpeakAsyncCancelAll()` method name. As one can see in the source code of the [`SpeechSynthesizer`](https://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Speech/Src/Synthesis/SpeechSynthesizer@cs/1/SpeechSynthesizer@cs) and [`VoiceSynthesis`](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Speech/Src/Internal/Synthesis/VoiceSynthesis@cs/1/VoiceSynthesis@cs) classes, there is quite some synchronous code involved in order to communicate with a background thread that does the actual voice synthesis. This code is actually quite heavy in that it uses multiple `lock` statements.

A best practice solution for this situation (multiple successive user interactions could create a series of code reactions but in the end we only want the last one) is to not directly start the reaction, but start a timer and only perform the reaction if there was no other user interaction in the meantime.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SpeechSynthesizer _speech = new SpeechSynthesizer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = 500;
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Reset timer
        timer1.Stop();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();

        _speech.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
        _speech.SpeakAsync(numericUpDown1.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

You should allow the user to configure the timer interval to chose a good compromise based on their system performance and their individual usage patterns. People who need audio assistance often consider  for good reasons a too long delay between user activity and an audio response as wasting their time. So it is important that users can configure such a delay to best fit their individual needs.

Comment: Timer! Simple and elegant. Wish I'd spotted that!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have taken Neil's excellent comment into consideration, and checked the repeat rate of the `NumericUpDown` control on the other PCs "without" calling the speech engine. Good.

Your code looks right. The `SpeakAsyncCancelAll` and `SpeakAsync` do not block and are "expected" to be running on a background thread. When I attempted to reproduce the problem (not a shocker) your code works fine on my PC using the test condition you describe. That being the case, maybe you could try a couple of variations on the slim chance that something makes a difference and yields some kind of clue by ruling out some unlikely issues.

---

**Variation 1**

Capture the "text to say" and post the work using `BeginInvoke`. This ensures that nothing could possibly be interfering with the `ValueChanged` or `MouseDown` messages from pumping in the message queue.

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Make 100% sure that the up-down ctrl is decoupled from speak call.
    var say = $"{numericUpDown1.Value}";

    // Ruling out an unlikely problem
    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        _speech.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
        _speech.SpeakAsync(say);
    });
}
```

---

**Variation 2**

Since you have a suspicion that something is running on the UI thread that shouldn't be, go ahead and give explicit instructions to post it on a background Task. At least we can rule that out.

```
private void numericUpDown2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Make 100% sure that the up-down ctrl is decoupled from speak call.
    var say = $"{numericUpDown2.Value}";

    // Ruling out an unlikely problem
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _speech.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
        _speech.SpeakAsync(say);
    });
}
```

---

**Variation 3 - Inspired by NineBerry's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74975629/5438626)** (added to test code project repo)

```
/// <summary>
/// Watchdog timer inspired by NineBerry.
/// https://stackoverflow.com/a/74975629/5438626
/// Please accept THAT answer if this solves your issue.
/// </summary>
int _changeCount = 0;
private void numericUpDown3_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var captureCount = ++_changeCount;
    var say = $"{numericUpDown3.Value}";
    Task
        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))
        .GetAwaiter()
        .OnCompleted(() => 
        {
            if(captureCount.Equals(_changeCount))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(say);
                _speech.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
                _speech.SpeakAsync(say);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/speech-synthesis-repro.git) this test code.

Answer (score 0):

Well the above answers do not solve the issue.  However, all the tested computers were dell computers. By default when the OS is installed, Dell installs a sound utility called MaxWaves which allows different audio enhancements.  Although all options are off in this utility, it appears that it buffers the sound and when an Async.CancelAll() call comes, it blocks until the sound duration is complete.  Therefore everything appears to slow to a crawl.
Uninstalling this utility as well as disabling it as a service corrects the problem.
Everything now works correctly.  Thank you for your answers.